# Verilog count odd and even numbers in ram

Tags: verilog

I'm using quartus 2 9.1 .I have a program of Single-Port RAM on verilog, i added reg

> Even

to check is number odd or even by first bit, its 1 or 0 in sumulation. I need to enter 16 numbers in ram by data input, then count how many odd and even numbers. But i tried something like:

```
output wire [4:0] count;
count = count + data[0]; //to count odd numbers, then i could take away from 16 and get even number - in simulation its just 0 or 1..
```

or something like that:

```
output wire [4:0] count;
always @*
begin
if(data[0])
even=1;
else
    begin
    even=0;
    count = count + 1;
    end
end
```

But count dont want show in sumaliton number of odd or even numbers.. My code:

```
   module kok 
( 
input [7:0] data, 
input [5:0] addr, 
input we, clk, 
output [7:0] q, 
output reg even 
); 

// Declare the RAM variable 
reg [7:0] ram[63:0]; 

// Variable to hold the registered read address 
reg [5:0] addr_reg; 

always @ (posedge clk) 
begin 
// Write 
if (we) 
ram[addr] <= data; 

addr_reg <= addr; 

end 

always @(posedge data) 
begin 
even = data[0]; 
end 

// Continuous assignment implies read returns NEW data. 
// This is the natural behavior of the TriMatrix memory 
// blocks in Single Port mode. 
assign q = ram[addr_reg]; 

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of your question is you want an output `count` signal that counts how many times you have an even value.

Create a top_level

```
module top (
     input [7:0] data, 
     input [5:0] addr, 
     input we
);
  reg clk= 1;
  initial begin
    forever #5 clk = ~clk;
  end

  reg reset_count = 0;
  initial begin
    #5 reset_count = 1'b1;
    #20 reset_count = 1'b0;
  end

  kok u_kok (.clk(clk),
             .data(data),
             .addr(addr),
             .we(we),
             .reset_count(reset_count)
             );
endmodule
```

Add this to `module_kok`:

```
module kok 
( 
input       reset_count,
input [7:0] data, 
input [5:0] addr, 
input we, clk, 
output [7:0] q, 
output reg even,
output reg [4:0] count
); 

// Declare the RAM variable 
reg [7:0] ram[63:0]; 

// Variable to hold the registered read address 
reg [5:0] addr_reg; 

always @ (posedge clk) 
begin 
// Write 
if (we) 
  ram[addr] <= data; 
addr_reg <= addr; 
end 

always @(posedge clk) 
begin
  even <= data[0]; 
end

  always @(posedge even or posedge reset_count)
begin
  if (reset_count) begin
    count <= 'h0;
  end
  else begin
    count <= count+1'b1;
  end
end


// Continuous assignment implies read returns NEW data. 
// This is the natural behavior of the TriMatrix memory 
// blocks in Single Port mode. 
assign q = ram[addr_reg]; 

endmodule
```

Note that you can only count to 2**5=32 before the counter overflows.

Here is a working example: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/qRs

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, but in simulation i got this : [IMGUR](http://i.imgur.com/vGT1hZs.png)

Comment: How to connect clock?)

Comment: Where do you instantiate your module?

Comment: In quartus 2 9.1 SP2 on notebook, verilog hdl

Comment: ok thats not what I meant. I would suggest you go read a few tutorials and introductory courses on verilog first. You need a top module to instantiate you module kok. Then you hook up your clock. If you are doing this on the FPGA, you can hook up a clock input through one of the pins. How are you toggling the data input? You need to toggle clock similarly...

Comment: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/8gCPxi8.png) I'm going to waveform, then select area about 10 ns and clicking forcing high (1) or forcing (0) like on this screenshot, i put in data, should i put 1, 0, 1 , 0 etc. in clock?

Comment: you need to do the same for clock but at a faster frequency

Comment: Thanks, i'm put 2000MHZ to clock, [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/17rNDqF.png) but even always 1 and count not working..(

Comment: Oh i didn't see top module, when i try to compile with module top i get error: http://i.imgur.com/7IoWoNk.png

Comment: In your previous screenshot, I see count working. Why do you say it is not? 
You can replace `bit` with `reg`

Comment: OK I made a mistake with the `begin` and `end`. Please try the above code now.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/VL2mXjX.png
Y now its compiling good, but its count periods of clock when number is odd, and even(must bee named odd) output always show 1, but need 0 when first bit is 0. I wanted to count how many even and odd numbers in data, on this screen in data 6 numbers, 4 are odd, and 2 are even.

Comment: OK I see what is wrong. I updated the code. Please note that you need a reset for your counter so it is initially reset to `'h0` and can start counting from there. Otherwise you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: Oh man very good, its now almost what i wanted) But if odd numbers going together, counter does not discriminate them 
http://i.imgur.com/uv4mUcx.png

Comment: Also i tried to run code on edaplayground, but its ask about validate account and i cant register its asks email company or university and its dont like my email

Comment: Thats right. If you have 2 odd numbers in a row, the counter won't increment. I will leave that to you to figure out how to do it. It is a small change in the code above. Good luck! And please accept the answer by clicking the Check mark

Comment: Oh i didnt see this button, done, thank you very much, i will try now to find this small change:)
And the last question, is any option to output the finally counter number in one string for example odd?

Comment: Nope. It's digital hardware just 1s and 0s

Comment: Ok, thanks. Looks like i'm stupid, because i cant find what i should change in code.. can you say what?)

Comment: I'm thinked about it whole day, count works when signal even changes, but i need this (count <= count + 1) statement work when even=1, but always constuct works when signal changes. Its like i need one more output signal, which will change when numbers in data going together and !=0, hmmm

Comment: Now you're thinking! play around with the code a bit and try and figure out what condition you need to increment count..

Answer (score 0):

The counter needs to be in a clocked process (i.e. inside an always @posedge clk). The counter therefore also needs to be a reg (instead of wire). You also need to figure out which condition(s) should restart your counter, and if you need to accound for overflow conditions etc. This depends on your actual use.

Comment: How i can figure out condition there?
`module kok 
( 
input [7:0] data, 
input [5:0] addr, 
input we, clk, 
output [7:0] q, 
output reg odd, 
output [7:0] qd 
); 
reg [7:0] cnt; 
assign qd = cnt; 

reg [7:0] ram[63:0]; 
reg [5:0] addr_reg; 

always @* 
begin 
odd = data[0]; 
end 

always @ (posedge clk) 
begin 
if(odd) 
cnt = cnt + 1; 
// Write 
if (we) 
ram[addr] <= data; 

addr_reg <= addr; 

end 

assign q = ram[addr_reg]; 

endmodule`
[simulation screen](http://i.imgur.com/pwoz5Wg.png)

Comment: Well, if you want to figure out on which condition the counter should be reset, you need to know how you want your counter to behave. For instance, you say you should count 16 operations, but you don't seem to have an input to your module indicating when those 16 operations are completed?